# Is there any du (disk usage) command flag that summarizes the size for each sub-directory

Tags: linux, command-line

I have the following directory structure (example) -

```
main
|--src
    |--com
        |- company
    |--org
        |- apache
|--resources
    |--abc
|--etc
```

I need the disk space used by each sub-directory under the `main` directory. So, the output would be something like -

```
user@main> du -{command_switches}
1M  src
20M resources
3M  etc
```

I have tried several switches available - sh, Sh,  ash, aSH - but I could not get the required result.

Comment: If you don't need that information put it a file or something like that, you could try `ncdu` which shows what you need in an interactive TUI environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some `du` implementations support `-d`¹ to limit the depth at which disk usage is displayed (not at which disk usage is *accounted*), so `du -hd 1 .` should work for the current directory.

Portably, you can always do:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type d -exec du -s {} +
```

(add `-h` if your `du` implementation supports it)

Though note that if there are a lot of directories in the current directory, `find` may end up running several invocations of `du` which could mean that some hard links are counted several times. Some `du` implementations also don't prevent hard links from being counted several times if  they're encountered through the traversal of different arguments.

---

<sup>¹, with older versions of GNU `du`, you may need `--max-depth` instead. The `-d` short option equivalent was only added in coreutils 8.8 for compatibility with FreeBSD</sup>

Comment: Also `du -sh main/*`.

Comment: @MichaelHomer, that would also report the disk usage of non-directory files and exclude hidden directory files. With zsh, you could do `du -sh main/*(D/)`

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into

> `$ du --max-depth=1 -h`

I know this thread is about `du` but you might also want to have a look at graphical applications, which can be more efficient at showing information like this, such as baobab or k4dirstat.

Comment: `du -d` (aka `--max-depth` in GNU du) is already mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: @Francisco, the graphical tools sound interesting. I will give them a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing what you're asking for, but I think

```
du -sh *
```

does exactly what you want. The `*` is important here. With `-s`, you get a summary for each directory *on the command line*, so with no explicit dir (implicit `.`) you would just get a summary for everything, not the for each of the dirs under the top-level individually.

Comment: I tried this command. It does not include directories start with `.`

Comment: @RakeshN: If you want to include them you need either add extra patterns for them (`.[!.]* ..?*`) or use the bash-specific `shopt -s dotglob` to make `*` match dotfiles.