# How can I sort du results by time *and* restrict to --max-depth=1

Tags: ls, disk-usage

I use rsync to back up my files using `--link-dest` to sync only differences from the last backup folder.

Is there anyway I can see a directory listing ordered by date **and** restricting it to `--max-depth=1` or `-d 1`?

For instance, this shows depth of one directory:

```
$ du -h --max-depth=1
33G     ./05-12-2021-16:00
4.7G    ./05-12-2021-12:30
4.6G    ./05-12-2021-11:30
11G     ./06-12-2021-13:30
4.8G    ./06-12-2021-02:00
19M     ./06-12-2021-08:58
4.7G    ./05-12-2021-21:00
938M    ./05-12-2021-02:11
754M    ./05-12-2021-19:00
32M     ./06-12-2021-02:30
179M    ./05-12-2021-13:30
172M    ./05-12-2021-17:30
4.7G    ./05-12-2021-22:00
752M    ./05-12-2021-20:00
170M    ./05-12-2021-17:00
4.7G    ./06-12-2021-12:01
934M    ./05-12-2021-12:00
38M     ./05-12-2021-14:00
175M    ./06-12-2021-12:31
34M     ./05-12-2021-18:00
388M    ./05-12-2021-16:30
42M     ./06-12-2021-14:01
4.7G    ./05-12-2021-00:54
756M    ./06-12-2021-11:33
173M    ./06-12-2021-00:31
4.5G    ./06-12-2021-15:31
31M     ./06-12-2021-00:00
1007M   ./05-12-2021-23:01
762M    ./05-12-2021-22:30
31M     ./05-12-2021-21:30
765M    ./06-12-2021-15:01
214M    ./05-12-2021-10:44
32M     ./06-12-2021-01:30
33M     ./06-12-2021-13:00
27M     ./05-12-2021-15:00
166M    ./05-12-2021-11:00
32M     ./06-12-2021-01:01
176M    ./05-12-2021-02:30
27M     ./05-12-2021-15:30
30M     ./05-12-2021-18:30
37M     ./05-12-2021-13:00
31M     ./05-12-2021-20:30
753M    ./05-12-2021-23:30
752M    ./05-12-2021-19:30
43M     ./06-12-2021-14:30
38M     ./05-12-2021-14:30
91G     .
```

Using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958885), it sorts by size, but recurses fully into each directory:

```
$ command ls -dt */ | while IFS= read -r dir; do du -sh "$dir"; done
33G     05-12-2021-00:54/
33G     05-12-2021-02:11/
33G     05-12-2021-02:30/
33G     05-12-2021-10:44/
33G     05-12-2021-11:00/
33G     05-12-2021-11:30/
33G     05-12-2021-12:00/
33G     05-12-2021-12:30/
33G     05-12-2021-13:00/
33G     05-12-2021-13:30/
33G     05-12-2021-14:00/
33G     05-12-2021-14:30/
33G     05-12-2021-15:00/
33G     05-12-2021-15:30/
33G     05-12-2021-16:00/
33G     05-12-2021-16:30/
33G     05-12-2021-17:00/
33G     05-12-2021-17:30/
33G     05-12-2021-18:00/
33G     05-12-2021-18:30/
33G     05-12-2021-19:00/
33G     05-12-2021-19:30/
33G     05-12-2021-20:00/
33G     05-12-2021-20:30/
33G     05-12-2021-21:00/
33G     05-12-2021-21:30/
33G     05-12-2021-22:00/
33G     05-12-2021-22:30/
33G     05-12-2021-23:01/
33G     05-12-2021-23:30/
33G     06-12-2021-00:00/
33G     06-12-2021-00:31/
33G     06-12-2021-01:01/
33G     06-12-2021-01:30/
33G     06-12-2021-02:00/
33G     06-12-2021-02:30/
23G     06-12-2021-08:58/
33G     06-12-2021-11:33/
33G     06-12-2021-12:01/
33G     06-12-2021-12:31/
33G     06-12-2021-13:00/
33G     06-12-2021-13:30/
33G     06-12-2021-14:01/
33G     06-12-2021-14:30/
33G     06-12-2021-15:01/
33G     06-12-2021-15:31/
33G     06-12-2021-16:03/
```

What I need, is the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205677/how-to-sort-du-h-max-depth-1-ordering-by-folder-name) question, but ordered by time / date.

I've had a look at the answers here, but I can't see anything helpful:
https://superuser.com/questions/147027/how-can-i-sort-the-output-of-ls-by-last-modified-date
[Is there any du (disk usage) command flag that summarizes the size for each sub-directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440369/is-there-any-du-disk-usage-command-flag-that-summarizes-the-size-for-each-sub)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272935/unix-command-size-of-directory-with-order-by-size
[How to recursively find the amount stored in directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67806/how-to-recursively-find-the-amount-stored-in-directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way, if your `du` supports `--time` flag:

```
du --max-depth=1 --time | sort -k 2
```

The solution to your second example, without showing the recursive size is to add `-S` flag to `du`:

```
ls -dt */ | while IFS= read -r dir; do du -Ssh "$dir"; done
```

But this command is unnecessarily complicated. You could make it easier:

```
du -Ssh "$(ls -Qdt /*)"
```

Comment: Thanks aviro. I awarded the answer to @Stephan as he replied a few minutes earlier and the output is more succinct, but I also upvoted your reply.

Comment: Hi aviro, in fact, you're correct and I've now awarded you the answer. The reason I didn't notice this is because, as you correctly say, the folder names coincidentally sort by date (since they are named after the date / time). PS: looks like `-d 1` is the same as `--max-depth=1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of `du` into `sort -k 2` to sort the results based on the second column:

`du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -k 2`